# retain rowID after dplyr filter

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I filter with dyplr and would like to retain the rowID after following filter steps - which I do not achieve after the filtering!

The filtering steps have the aim to get high values within one of the particular columns, where all other values from all other columns are low(er) in that same row!

```
set.seed(1)
df = data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:100,1000,rep=TRUE)))
colnames(df) = stringi::stri_rand_strings(10, 10)
rownames(df) = stringi::stri_rand_strings(1000, 10)
df %>% filter("eJra6Jvlss" > 60 ) %>% select(-one_of("eJra6Jvlss")) %>% filter_all( all_vars(. < 50))
```

Comment: I would use `df %>% rownames_to_column('rn') %>% filter(....) %>% column_to_rownames('rn')` because `tidyverse` wouldn't allow for row names other than the default numeric index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rownames_to_column` to create a rowname column as the `tidyverse` functions drops the rownames while doing the processsing and then after the `filter` step, use `column_to_rownames` to create the rownames from the same column that was already created

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    rownames_to_column('rn') %>%
    filter(eJra6Jvlss > 60 ) %>%
    select(-eJra6Jvlss) %>% 
    filter_at(vars(-rn), all_vars(. < 50)) %>%
    column_to_rownames('rn')
#        xBffQ5oY5h 4aX8spSZ9w Eus4cdtPBA AbNMxhTLIE AUrPGAOGIF MgVuoQ9kqQ J4jHzuOOly w8b42QfV6E enIvKl4CAz
#7ZXa4jczXs         47         34         33          6         43     44         37         15         35
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R maintains the row names while filtering. You could first select rows where `eJra6Jvlss` is greater than 60 and then subset rows where all values are less than 50.

```
temp_df  <- subset(df, eJra6Jvlss > 60, select = -eJra6Jvlss) 
temp_df[rowSums(temp_df < 50) == ncol(temp_df), ]

#           xBffQ5oY5h 4aX8spSZ9w Eus4cdtPBA AbNMxhTLIE AUrPGAOGIF MgVuoQ9kqQ J4jHzuOOly w8b42QfV6E enIvKl4CAz
#7ZXa4jczXs         47         34         33          6         43         44         37         15         35
```